# Simple Python - How to change a variable with every repeat of a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables

My code is for a dice game.  It has five rounds and adds up the total at the end of each round.  I want to find a way to be able to add all five round totals together at the end of the player's go.  I was thinking that the easiest way to do this is to change the name of the round total variable at the end of each loop, eg. roundtotal1, roundtotal2, etc.  But I'm not sure and I'd like to see what you think.  Thanks :)

My code:

```
import random
import time

p1 = ('Bob')
p2 = ('Larry')

#PLAYER 1'S TURN

print('Welcome to Dice Game,',p1)

#Prints round number of 5 rounds
for x in range (1,6):
    round = ('%s' % x)
    print('Round %s' % x)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print()

#Rolls the first die
    input('Press ENTER to roll your first die...')
    num1 = random.randint(1,6)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('You scored a',num1,'on your first roll!\n')

#Rolls the second die
    time.sleep(2)
    input('Press ENTER to roll your second die...')
    num2 = random.randint(1,6)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('You scored a',num2,'on your second roll!\n')

#If dice rolls 1 and 2 are the same, roll a third die
    time.sleep(1)
    num3 = 0
    if num1 == num2:
        num3 = random.randint(1,6)
        print('As you rolled a double, you get a third die!')
        input('Press enter to roll your third die...')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('You scored a',num3,'on your third roll!\n')
    else:
        pass

#Print the total for the round
    time.sleep(1)
    roundtotal = num1+num2+num3
    print('ROUND TOTAL:',roundtotal)
    print()
    print()

print('GAME TOTAL:',) #Round totals from rounds 1-5 added together
#How do I do this?
```

Comment: Collect all values in a list?

Comment: At the top of the code before the main loop, make a variable `grandtotal = 0`.  As the last step in the main loop, add roundtotal to grandtotal.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set another variable that just adds whatever you roll, so it would be defined `total1 = 0` near the start of your code and then after the line `num1 = random.randint(1,6)` adding `total1 += num1` will have you store the total for your rolls in that variable, so you can use it later on.

If you want to store all the rolls a player has individually in a single variable then you could use the concept of lists